# Android convert the ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> mylist to stringarray

Tags: android, arraylist

I have create an android application program..I dont know how to convert the  `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> mylist` to string array..pls tell some idea.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `ArrayList<String>`, traverse the "mylist", append one after one element into newly created list and finally use `toArray(T[])` method of `newly` created list to obtain a string array.

Comment: You are right.But if he will create ArrayList<String>.He can directly add those into array.Is not it ?

Comment: So why should he create Arralist<String> ? He can take add the item directly to String array.

Comment: @AndroidPower - how she/he will determines the count of strings in that collection?