# How to Convert ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> to a StringArray?

Tags: android

I want to store a String array in the database, but I got values from another activity as an `ArrayList<Hashmap<String, String>>`. How should I convert this ArrayList into a String array?

Code:

```
HashMap <String, String> h1 = new HashMap <String, String> ();
h1.put("member_id", member_id);
h1.put("categoryname", category_name);
h1.put("routinetype", routine_type);
h1.put("targettype", target_type);
h1.put("days", countOfDays);
h1.put("point", points);
h1.put("daystring", listOfDayString);
h1.put("create_date", strDate);
arrayList1.add(h1);
```

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592730/android-convert-the-arraylisthashmapstring-string-mylist-to-stringarray

Comment: @ Gunjan luthra :  HashMap<String, String> h1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    h1.put("member_id", member_id);
    h1.put("categoryname", category_name);
    h1.put("routinetype", routine_type);
    h1.put("targettype", target_type);
    h1.put("days", countOfDays);
    h1.put("point", points);
    h1.put("daystring", listOfDayString);
    h1.put("create_date", strDate);
arrayList1.add(h1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use:

```
String[] strArray = new String[urArrayList.size()];
strArray = urArrayList.toArray(strArray);
```

#### EDIT:

Then you can simply use this:

```
int i = 0;
String strArr[] = new String[urArrayList.size()];
for (HashMap<String, String> hashMap : urArrayList) {
 for (String value : hashMap.values()) {
    strArr[i] = value ;
    i++;

 }
}
```

Comment: Hashmap can not be converted into Stringarray for this solution.